# Unable to query and view parent and child opportunity

Tags: apex, visualforce, compile-error

[image]

I am converting this code into parent and son opportunity

```
public class accconhierarchy {
    Private list<account> acc;

    public List<accountWrap> accountList { get; set; }
    public accconhierarchy (){
        List<contactWrap> cw;
        accountList = new List<accountWrap>();
        acc = [select id,name,industry,billingcountry,createdbyid,(select id,name,email,phone from contacts) from account limit 20];
        for(account a:acc){
            cw = new list<contactWrap>();
            For(contact co : a.contacts){
               cw.add(new contactWrap(co));
            }
            accountList.add(new accountWrap(a,false,cw));
        }
    }

    public class accountWrap{
        public account oAccount{get;set;}
        public boolean isSelected{get;set;}
        public List<contactWrap> contactset{get;set;}
        public accountWrap(account a,boolean b, List<contactWrap> c){
            oAccount=a;
            isSelected=b;
            contactset =c;            
        }
    }

    public class contactWrap{
        public contact oContact{get;set;}
        public boolean isSelected{get;set;}        
        public contactWrap(contact a){
            oContact=a;
            isSelected=false;                       
        }
    }

}
```

enter image description here

I am converting this code in such a way that parent and child opportunities view

parent opportunity lookup field is Parent_opportunity__c

```
public class accconhierarchy {
    Private list<opportunity> acc;
    Private list<opportunity> acc1;

    public List<accountWrap> accountList { get; set; }
     public List<contactWrap> cw { get; set; }
    public accconhierarchy (){
        List<contactWrap> cw;
        accountList = new List<accountWrap>();
        acc = [select id,name,parent_opportunity__c,accountid from opportunity where parent_opportunity__c!=null];
         acc1 = [select id,name,parent_opportunity__c,accountid from opportunity where parent_opportunity__C=null];
        for(opportunity a:acc){
            cw = new list<contactWrap>();
            For(opportunity co : acc1){
               cw.add(new contactWrap(co));
            }
            accountList.add(new accountWrap(a,false,cw));
        }
    }

    public class accountWrap{
        public opportunity oAccount{get;set;}
        public boolean isSelected{get;set;}
        public List<contactWrap> contactset{get;set;}
        public accountWrap(opportunity a,boolean b, List<contactWrap> c){
            oAccount=a;
            isSelected=b;
            contactset =c;            
        }
    }

    public class contactWrap{
        public contact oContact{get;set;}
        public boolean isSelected{get;set;}        
        public contactWrap(contact a){
            oContact=a;
            isSelected=false;                       
        }
    }

}
```

I am getting error like this E cant able to query and view parent and son opportunity

> Error: accconhierarchy Compile Error: Constructor not defined:
>   [accconhierarchy.contactWrap].(Opportunity) at line 15 column 23

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to pass an Opportunity into the contactWrap constructor in the code below which is causing the error:

> accconhierarchy Compile Error: Constructor not defined:
>   [accconhierarchy.contactWrap].(Opportunity) at line 15 column 23

```
For(opportunity co : acc1){
    cw.add(new contactWrap(co));
}
```

Comment: How can i query : select id,name,(select id,name from parent_opportunity__r) from opportunity this is showing error and select id,name,(select id,name from opportunity) from parent_opportunity__c this is also error